# Android turn based multiplayer onTurnBasedMatchReceived doesn't trigger when game starts from Play Games

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

When i create a turn based game from my application and all players accept invitations in game then i'm able to control how each player takes turn by means of callback methods - onTurnBasedMatchReceived, onInvitationReceived etc. But when i start it from notification or from Play Games app i'm able just to take turn and another turn notification comes to Play Games but not in my callback methods. I'm wondering may be someone faced this situation too and is it possible to fix somehow?

Comment: you may need to attach a OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener to your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, not registered it properly when game starts with existing bundle.